# Is there a .png command like \includepdf[pages={x-y}]{Figures/Figure.pdf}

Tags: graphics, png

I'm making the cover for my master's thesis. I've used `\includepdf[pages={x-y}]{Figures/Figure.pdf}` to insert full-page PDFs, but my cover is a png. Is there any similar way to insert a full-page png?

Cheers Simon

Comment: You could try the `background` package and use `\includegraphics`

Comment: I was just writing the same comment --- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background?lang=en for a reference.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. you have a file `figure.png` and you want to include it as a cover page? please post a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the good old `\includegraphics` AND notice LaTeX to recognize the .png format (`\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`).

```
\documentclass{article}
%% ...
\usepackage{epsfig} %=>\includegrapics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps,.png,.jpg}
%% ...
\begin{document}
%% ...
\thispagestyle{empty} % to avoid page numbering on cover page
%% ...
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{coverpic.png}
%% ...
\newpage
%% ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `titlepage` environment (`\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`) is also worth mentioning as it handles the `\newpage` and `\thispagestyle{emtpy}` commands.

Comment: `epsfig` is old and deprecated. Just load `graphicx` and use `\includegraphics{filename}`. No need for extension, no need for `\DeclareGraphicxExtensions`.

Answer (score 1):

pdfpages builds up on graphicx and can handle png too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{example-image.png}
\end{document}
```

includes on my system:

```
<D:/MiKTeX2.9/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png>]
```

and gives this page:

[image]